# Get User's IP, Location, Device and other Log info in Laravel 7x

Tags: php, laravel-7

I need to Get User's IP, Location, Device and other Log info in Laravel 7x on my Registration and on every login event(s).

Can you please tell me the Laravel official existing or new package recommendations?

looking forward to hear from you soon, thanks.

I have used some older package not remember the name but I am expecting a newer and stable recommendations for Laravel 7x.